# fusion tables with ST_INTERSECT and JOIN

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I'm having trouble with this query using ST_INTERSECTS or ST_OVERLAPS.  It's not working with JOIN(s) functions.

```sql
SELECT T1.'ZIP', T2.name
  FROM 1fzwSGnxD0xzJaiYXYX66zuYvG0c5wcEUi5ZI0Q as T1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH as T2 
         ON ST_OVERLAPS(T1.'geometry', T2.geometry, 0.1)=1 LIMIT 1
```

I have tested these queries in many ways.
Here are two working examples one from each table pulling these same fields with aliases:

```sql
SELECT `ZIP` as z, `geometry` as gr FROM 1fzwSGnxD0xzJaiYXYX66zuYvG0c5wcEUi5ZI0Q

SELECT 'name' as n, 'geometry' as gl FROM 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH
```

You can use the  ' and ` around tables the same way for both from what I saw.

As soon as I do a join the queries stop working I have tried views and that failed too.
I tried ST_INTERSECTS that failed.
I tried overlap with =t instead of =1 and with out either one.

It seems to work best when I write it like this:

```sql
SELECT T1.'ZIP', T2.'name' FROM 1fzwSGnxD0xzJaiYXYX66zuYvG0c5wcEUi5ZI0Q as T1, 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH as T2 WHERE ST_OVERLAPS(T1.'geometry', T2.'geometry', 0.1)=1 LIMIT 1
```

but then it fails on every comma.

I tested these queries at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/fusiontables.query.sql

Any help would be great.

Comment: The table name 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH looks suspicious. Are you sure the "-" is supposed to be in there?

Comment: [Works for me](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH#map:id=3)

Comment: Where did ST_OVERLAPS come from? I only see ST_INTERSECTS and ST_DISTANCE in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference)

Comment: ST_OVERLAPS is supposed to be allowed I saw it somewhere in the docs.  here's a list of ST_Geometry types from oracle. http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/an_overv315896832.htm

Comment: More so than anything it works on any basic query but when you start adding joins or ST_ of any sort it fails.  I even made it into several queries breaking apart the geometry of one table and trying ST_INTERSECTS on points and coordinates. Then tried it with polygons the same way too.

Comment: One more note that may help using google maps api ST_ queries work fine.  select 'name' from 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH where ST_INTERSECTS('geometry',CIRCLE(LATLNG("+pslat+","+pslng+"),1)) limit 1  I used "),1" on this example because pslat, pslng are the location of the marker and I wanted it to be a little bigger kind of like rounding off the decimal places on your gps cards lat, lng

Comment: It was the OR clause.  I cant't use circle it needs to be POLYGON.  will update when I find the right code to create polygon.  I currently have this SELECT 'name' FROM 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('geometry', POLYGON((LATLNG(-120.8435, 40.249528),1), LATLNG(-121.061249, 40.258326),1),...) LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2):

had to do it as a polygon like this

```
SELECT 'name' FROM 1vVUoTyGcnlbxmd66lZeHj81-tbgpIyKpVmXaZxYH 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('geometry', 
POLYGON(
LATLNG(40.249528, -120.8435), 
LATLNG(40.258326, -121.061249), 
LATLNG(40.301765, -121.007911), 
LATLNG(40.249528, -120.8435)))
```

These were my results from zip 00012.  I'm assuming more than desired(will have to double check) but at least the query works.

fran id:50315
fran id:50204
fran id:51489
fran id:51318
fran id:51404
fran id:54023
fran id:53658
fran id:54404
fran id:50611
fran id:51406
fran id:53302